# Mudar cor de uma imagem ao passar o mouse sobre ela

Tags: html, css, eventos-do-mouse

Como faço efeito em `CSS` de passar o mouse sobre uma imagem ela aparecer com cores e ao retirar ela fique preto e branco?
Gostaria de fazer com `CSS` ou outro, sem ser com o flash(R.I.P.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar o `filter` do CSS3 exemplo:

```
<img src = "image_path" class="image">
```

E no CSS fazer assim:

```
.image{
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
}
.image:hover{
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(0%);
    transition: 1s;
}
```

O `transition` é apenas para dar um efeito mais suave.
Você só deve levar em consideração
que deve usar o prefixo `webkit` para os navegadores chrome, safari e opera.
O firefox 35+   e o edge 16+ já suportam sem precisar usar prefixo.

```css
.image{
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
}
.image:hover{
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(0%);
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="image">
```

Comment: Ia responder isso agora kkk, é o melhor do que criar duas imagens e acabar sobrecarregando o site.

Comment: `+1` nem sabia que dava para fazer isso com css

Comment: Valeu mesmo era isso mesmo :) Obrigado

Comment: Se a resposta lhe foi útil marque como respondida(a setinha verde em baixo da dos votos da pergunta) para que outras pessoas saibam que já está resolvida. ;)

Answer (score 0):

para isso o mais simples é mesmo ter duas imagens, para ficar como eu acho que quer será as duas terem exatamente a mesma medida, neste caso as imagens são diferentes mas é só para ilustrar:

HTML:

```
<img class="cores" src="http://cinemacao.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Scarlett-CAPA-2.jpg">
<img class="preto" src="https://cdn3.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/001/113/371/large/nehaal-gonsalves-scarlet-johansson-face.jpg?1443931918">
```

CSS:

```
 img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  transition: 1s;
}
.preto:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Um exemplo no [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pmn1ems/10/)

Comment: Obrigado Miguel, mas gostaria de algo mais sutil, um efeito mais prolongado entre as transições, obrigado

Comment: Editei de acordo, é só adicionar um tempo de transição (`transition`)

Answer (score 0):

Vendo seus comentários acredito que está seja uma forma que vai mais agradar já que é a mais sútil de todas e a mais leve.

É bem simples e utiliza WebKit do `css`, fiz uma imagem teste só pra você ver como vai ficar.

```css
img {
  /*opacidade*/
  opacity: 0.75;
  -moz-opacity: 0.75;
  filter: alpha(opacity=75);
  -webkit-filter: opacity(0.75);
  /*filtro P/B*/
  filter: gray;
  /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
  /*qualidade*/
  image-rendering: auto;
}
img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-filter: opacity(1);
  filter: none;
  /* Firefox 10+ */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
  image-rendering: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://essaseoutras.xpg.uol.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/circulos-coloridos.jpg">
```

É só passar o mouse e ele muda a cor, sem coisinhas que vão deixar o site mais lento ou sei lá.